# How to have json data dynamically in javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, javascript-objects

I have the following reactjs code -

```
const [interviewerDetails,setinterviewerDetails] =useState([]);
    useEffect(()=>{
    const getinterviewerDetails= async ()=>{
      const data1 = await axios.get("http://localhost:8083/api/GetProduct")
      .then(response => {
        console.log("role is "+response.data[0].role)
        setinterviewerDetails(response.data)
        console.log(interviewerDetails)
      })
     .catch(error => { console.log(error) })
     setinterviewerDetails(data1);
      };  
  getinterviewerDetails();
  },[])
  console.log("interviewerDetails : ", interviewerDetails)
```

Which is giving the following response in console -
[image]

Now, I want to have that json response as following -

```
var InterviewerObject = {
  "HR": {
    "Communication": ["Akshay ", "Images", "Tables", "Lists"], 
  },
  "Technical": {
    "PHP": ["Arvind Gupta", "Sri sharma", "Vidyut Tope"],
    "SQL": ["Akash Jha", "Mohit Mane", "Suresh Tupe"]
  }
}
```

I want to have select technical skill dynamically as PHP,SQL etc. And the firstname and lastname dynamically as Arvind Gupta , Sri sharma etc.

Can you please help me out ?

Comment: You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that people can understand your problem and help you. [see why you shouldn't post image as a code or an error](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question#:~:text=You%20should%20not%20post%20code,order%20to%20reproduce%20the%20problem.). Add you array here as well...

Comment: You definitely need `.reduce` but you have to provide more context to get an answer